# jQuery Tabs Find Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am hoping someone may help me to figure out a sticking point I am at. I have tabs that are wrapped in div's that are added dynamically so at any time I do not know how many there will be. Even so, if I was to have 3 tabs, like so:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

I am using HTML5 Drag and Drop. What I am trying to do is figure out if the current tag that I have is greater than or less than the tab that I am over so I can then drop it before or after the tab. I start to get coordinates for the getBoundingClientRect() for the element that I have, but I have not figured out how to determine whether I am greater than or less than the tab I am hovering over. For example, if I was dragging Tab 2, how would I figure out if I am past Tab 3 to drop it there after or if I dragged it before Tab 1 to drop it there.

Pretty much this gets down to being able to do some math, which I am not good at, and logic to add to my jQuery code to know where to drop the current tab I have.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Less math based approach to finding out where you're hovering but requires you add an index to each tab (dynamically or otherwise):

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab" data-index="0">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab" data-index="1">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab" data-index="2">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

Find the tab you're currently hovering over:

```
$('.tab').hover(function () {
  var index = $(this).data('index');
  console.log(index);
  console.log(this); // div itself
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And people say you don't need math to be a programmer. Hehe!

Just check the left of the dragged div against the center (left + width)/2 of the target divs. If it's less, it's left of that div. If it's higher, it's right of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: I did an example, that allow drop the element with larger id **before** element with smaller id.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  // get id of dragging element
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (data > ev.target.id) {
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabs')[0]
    parent.insertBefore(
      document.getElementById(data), ev.target);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab" id="1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab" id="2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab" id="3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

Refer here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful, just need to figure out how to do it with the tab class div's not having id's.

Comment: @pertrai1: If so may be complicated, you must find index of dragging element in list, and then compare. But after dropping, the index was changed, it don't make sense if index always change, don't have anything to keep track of indexes beside `id`. :|

Comment: That is a good point. Let me see what I can do about the  use of the id